# Specific condition in Case statement after 'THEN'

Tags: mysql

I need to update a temp table making use of a Case statement but there is a specific condition to use as part of the THEN - almost like a `WHERE` clause after the `THEN`.

So in my case statement if the `Days_to_maturity` is between 0 and 7 days then I need to extract the `7DAY` Rate from the 'Spot table'. If the 'Days_to_maturity' is between 7 and 30 days then I need to extract the `1MNTH` Rate. Lastly, when the 'Days_to_maturity' is between 30 and 60 days then I need to extract the `2MNTH` Rate

You can see below example the 3 rates are different for this specific USD & EUR combination for `7DAY`, `1MNTH` and `2MNTH` hence this Case statement to extract the correct rate.

[image: Example date from 'Spot' table]

I've done the Case statement as follows, but the correct data is not extracted.

[image: Case statement]

Comment: Please edit your question to add the request as text instead of an image. It seems to me the whole `CASE` is useless, as you can see it will always be the `spot.rate` field that will be used. I think all these conditions should be in the `inner join`'s `on` clause instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Case-Then statement with the where clause in the following way:

```
UPDATE #ResultsFX
SET
Daily_dif_ratel = spot.rate

FROM #ResultsFX AS r

inner join #Spotrates as spot on spot. Base CCY = rs. Buy Currency

AND spot. Rate CCY = rs. Sell Currency

where 
CASE WHEN r.Days_to_Maturity >= 0 AND r.Days_t_Maturity < 7 then 
spot.RateType='7DAY'
WHEN r.Days_to_Maturity >= 7 AND r.Days_to_Maturity < 30 then 
spot.RateType='1MNTH'
WHEN r.Days_to_Maturity >= 30 AND r.Days_to_Maturity < 60 then 
spot.RateType='2MNTH'
```